# Creating a function to check form data with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, function

I've created an array that contains a form data (the form and php scripts are in a single php file).

I need to create a function to specify which one of the array elements are empty.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $data=array("username"=>$_POST['username'],
        "email"=>$_POST['email'],
         "password1"=>$_POST['password1'],
         "password2"=>$_POST['password2'],
         "gender"=>$_POST['gender']);
    check($data);
}

function check(){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset ($_POST['email']) && isset ($_POST['password1'])){
        echo 'ok';
    }
    else{
        echo 'missing';
    }
}
```

Comment: *"...which one of the array elements are empty"* - So, use `empty()` ;-)

Comment: i know but it's not working

Comment: Which is the question? Is the code not working? Are you experiencing some error or exception?

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Sina you didn't pass the param $data in the function definition.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //only if form is submitted
    $data = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'password1' => $_POST['password1'],
        'password2' => $_POST['password2'],
        'gender' => $_POST['gender']        
    );
    check($data);
}

/**
 * @description: validates the form data
 * @return none
 * @params array($data)
 */
function check($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            echo ucwords($key)." is empty.<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks & Regards,

**Vivek**

Comment: @Sina You are most welcome. All the best wishes for you efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `foreach` :

```
function check($data)
{
     foreach($data as $key => $value)
     {
          echo $key . isset($data[$key]) ? ' Ok' : ' Missing';
     }
}
```

Edit : Fixed function with parameter

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Was it because it was not well indented ? I fixed it

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- My bad, then. I'll check twice the next time i post something

Comment: I meant, I also do not know why your answer was downvoted. Probably because of the `isset()` but that works.

Comment: `echo $key . isset($data[$key]) ? ' Ok' : ' Missing';` could be replaced by `echo !empty($data[$key]) ? 'Ok' : 'Missing' . " " . $key . " ";` which also works, if OP wants to check for "empty" rather than "isset".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Right. But it could also trick you. Taken from php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues), empty() return `FALSE` for `0`, `0.0` and `"0"`, wich can result in unwanting behaviour

Comment: Yes that could like you say, but it's an option that is still usable.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of solving this, you can use foreach with empty() and a second array to contain the empty elements list.

Follow these steps:

1. Use foreach to get the values
2. Read index value and check if (empty($_POST[$key]))
3. If it's empty, either echo it or save it in a second array to use it later.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation is one suggestion but have a read at this [good article](http://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/) on security and validations.

- $_POST exists?
- define a list of keys ( to iterate )
- do validations in loop ie.isset(),is_null(),empty(),striptags/slash, sanitize etc.

Example:

```
if(empty($_POST)) {
  // handle error ie. redirect      
}

// define required keys or as constants using define();
$post_keys = array(
  'username',
  'email"'
  'password1',
  'password2',
  'gender'
);

foreach($post_keys as $k => $v) {
  // _isValid() is optional 
  // ie. or revalidate email format, empty string, blah etc.
  // if(!isset($_POST[$k]) || !_isValid($k, $v)) { .. }

  if(!isset($_POST[$k]) {
    // handle error
  }
}

// everything ok, do stuffs ie.$_POST['username'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for some reason, my formatter is not functioning.. hmm